# Bring Windows Taskbar to front when a fullscreen application is running

Tags: c#, winapi

I have an app where I use a notifyicon to show some balloon tips. However, it will be running in an environment where there is always a separate main app running in full-screen mode. My problem is making the taskbar come to front - I thought it would automatically when there are balloon tips appearing on the notifyicon in the system tray.

Can I make the taskbar become visible over the app running in full-screen mode?

I have tried the following but it's not a case of hiding or unhiding the taskbar - it's a case of bringing it to the front or making the running app not full-screen...

```
int TaskBarHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "");
bool result1 = SetWindowPos(TaskBarHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);   // Hide Taskbar
bool result1 = SetWindowPos(TaskBarHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // Show Taskbar
```

***EDIT***
There must be a way of doing this - if I am watching a movie and my battery is low then the taskbar slides up and I get a notification about the battery. I need to find out what the OS does to get this behaviour...

***EDIT***
It is worth saying that the sourcecode for the fullscreen app is under our control. This does change the question in fairness but I would still like to know a way of "interrupting" a fullscreen app regardless of whether you have control or not.

Comment: Notifications shouldn't be showing over full screen apps - I don't want them interrupting my presentation or my movie.

Comment: Appreciate the response Michael but rather than telling me what your preference is when you watch movies etc. can you offer an answer to the question posed? If you read the question again I do not ask whether it should be done, I ask if it can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little too subtle.  Notifications shouldn't be showing over full screen apps, and the system does actively try to block such behavior, which is why you're having problems.

Comment: Okay, that is fair enough and makes sense - a good OS should block such things, cheers for clearing that up. The full-screen app in this case runs on a proprietary handheld device whose sole purpose is to run that app. However the 2nd app should display notifications when there are updates available - these are getting lost behind the full-screen...

Comment: I'm thinking now (after reading a good bit on this) that a custom control - like a semi-transparent winform - would be a better solution here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I'm looking at doing it now is by sending the escape key from my notifyicon app.

```
SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```

This works as the standard behaviour for a fullscreen app is usually to exit the fullscreen mode when escape is hit on the keyboard. I still don't think this is the best solution because there may be times when forcing an ESC might have side effects if the user is doing something else...but it may well be "just good enough"

Answer (score 1):

If it's no problem that the start menu will popup than you could press the windows button.

```
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Works fine for me under Windows 7.

Comment: That's a workable solution alright but I've gone for the option of sending the ESC key. This is expected behaviour anyway - that a full-screen app responds to the ESC key by exiting full-screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely technical point of view, this is a very interesting question. The first thing that comes to mind is by far not an elegant solution, but maybe a working solution - open the Start Menu:

```
SendMessage(hAnyWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0)
```

I will see if I can find another solution.

(Well, the most obvious solution, of course, is to `BringWindowToTop(hTaskBar)`, but that appears not to work.)

Answer (score 0):

How about the other solution?

Not to make the main application full-screen: it will cover the whole screen view except the area where the taskbar is always positioned by default. If the taskbar is repositioned to other side, the application will be notified by OS to refresh its window size, but it will always avoid the  new taskbar area. The worst case is when the taskbar is set auto-hidden. It will not look so nice though.

Comment: In my case, the app needs to be fullscreen to get the most screen real estate possible - this is not negotiable!

Comment: How about setting the property of the Windows Taskbar to always be in front (by right-clicking for the properties of the taskbar and set it on top of other windows option)? 

It will always make any notification balloon from the system tray icon to appear in front as well. In my case, the taskbar is always locked and is not auto-hidden.

Comment: An app running in fullscreen mode will still appear over all the other windows including the taskbar so although the notifications will still happen, they will not be seen.